# What is '?' is meaning in url?

Tags: api, http, url, https, request

I'm writing code and when I type in the earthquake API link I noticed a '?' in the link and then I try to find information about it but no progress.

What is the meaning of `'?'` in url like this:

```
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?starttime=2014-01-01&endtime=2014-01-02
```

I'm seeing this in other sites like Youtube or google, for example: `query?`, `watch?`, `count?`, `search?`:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

https://www.google.com/search?q=pi&sxsrf=APwXEdfoougSC4O6KeDi5afxiy0rL671Rg%3A1685072498601&source=hp&ei=cipwZKTQIpCUrwSHkqKgCQ&iflsig=AOEireoAAAAAZHA4gq4mE-4ZNz8m747alblR3ZAPLE84&ved=0ahUKEwik0cqdiJL_AhUQyosKHQeJCJQQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=pi&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyDAgjEIoFEBMQgAQQJzIHCCMQigUQJzINCAAQigUQsQMQgwEQQzIHCAAQigUQQzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyCggAEIoFELEDEEMyBwgAEIoFEEMyCwgAEIAEELEDEIMBMhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6BwgjEOoCECc6BAgjECc6BAgAEANQohRY9RVgvRloAnAAeACAAfABiAHRA5IBAzItMpgBAKABAbABCg&sclient=gws-wiz
```

Answer (score 1):

The ? is the start of the query parameter in the URL. Query parameters are a defined set of parameters attached to the end of a URL. They are extensions of the URL that are used to help define specific content or actions based on the data being passed. To append query params to the end of a URL, a ‘?’ is added followed immediately by a query parameter.